# firefox url rewriting mysteriously, but not other browsers

Tags: apache, firefox, redirect, ssl, haproxy

I have a bizarre problem that only (so far) manifests itself in Firefox, where it rewrites the URL to a different domain (also hosted by us). The rewrite however does not occur in Safari or Chrome (I'm testing from a MacBook Pro).

My setup is this: The loadbalancer running HAProxy listening on 80 an internally 8080 and Apache listening on 443. Traffic on 80 is passed to the backend, traffic from Apache is SSL decrypted then sent to localhost:8080 and then passed to the backend's port 8443.  On the backend, any traffic from 80 is considered non-SSL, but on 8443 is considered decrypted SSL.  Backend servers are running Apache.

If I go to https://www.sslexample.com/ (henceforth SSL_DOMAIN) from any browser on an SSL site, everything behaves as it should.  It hits the Apache SSL accelerator, is decrypted, passed to the proxy, then sent to the backend.  If I go to http://www.nonsslexample.com/ (henceforth NONSSL_DOMAIN), again, everything behaves as expected for a non-SSL site, it hits the proxy, then the backend, and non-SSL traffic is served as expected.

Here's where things get weird.  If I go to SSL_DOMAIN via http, what's supposed to happen is that I'm redirected to https.  For one of our mixed SSL/non-SSL domains, this works as expected from all browsers.  BUT on Firefox (and sometimes on Safari for my colleague and never on Chrome) if I go to SSL_DOMAIN via http, the first thing that happens is that the URL is immediately rewritten to the NONSSL_DOMAIN and I'm redirected to the completely different domain.

Huh?

Looking at the logs on the LB, Chrome and Safari behave as they should--hit the lb on port 80--but Firefox never hits the loadbalancer with the SSL_DOMAIN on port 80.  But the time to LB sees it, it's already been rewritten.

I installed the Tamper Data plugin on Firefox, and the results confused me more.  The initial correct URL header never receives a reply header.  It's immediately replaced with the incorrect one.  And things carry on as if I had intended the non-SSL URL.

I looked in my /etc/hosts file (since this is in testing and we're overriding these domains), and everything looks correct.

If you have ever encountered a problem like this before, I'd be very grateful for tips on how to debug it.

Comment: Which domain are you redirected to? Sounds suspicious. Malware-ish.

Comment: Do you use 301 rdirect instead of 302? With 301 the browser does not need to re-request something he has already done. Try to quit the browser, remove 301 for 302 and re-check with tamper data and live http headers.

Comment: As much as I hate it, it appears to be a problem isolated to Firefox on MacOS. I cannot replicate the problem on Windows or Linux, both from inside our network or outside it.  

I ran wireshark on my localhost, and in the (wrong) firefox case, the rewrite happened BEFORE any network traffic occurred, then the wrong website was fetched.

Comment: Also, DarkXphenomenon, I am redirected to our own other non-ssl domain. Do you think we have malware on our server?

Answer (score 1):

regilero is right.

I just experienced the same problem with Firefox and Safari on Mac OS X 10.9.1. They both seem to cache 301 redirects and rewrite internally on the next request to the once redirected URL.

This is quite funny, especially if you try to write and test redirects in your webserver config.

The solution for me was to empty the browser cache. Then the redirect will be read again from the server. I had to do this every time I wanted the redirect to be read again.